# Объединение токенов в шейдерах OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengles

Мне нужно в шейдере для имени структуры (Name) сформировать соответствующее ему уникальное имя (cbName). Это делает следующий макрос:

```
#define CONCATENATE(prefix, name) prefix##name

CONCATENATE(cb, Name)
```

Проблема в том, что это работает в шейдере OpenGL при запуске на Windows, но не работает в шейдере OpenGLES3 (использую #version 300 es) при запуске на Android (компилятор шейдера ругается на неожиданный символ '#'). Есть ли какая-либо возможность сделать это в шейдерах OpenGLES3?

UPD:

Следующие варианты также не работают

```
#define CONCATENATE2(prefix, name) prefix##name
#define CONCATENATE(prefix, name) CONCATENATE2(prefix, name)

#define CONCATENATE(prefix, name) prefix/**/name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ж директивы препроцессора C - так что скормите ваш файл с шейдером препроцессору, и полученный полуфабрикат сохраните, а потом уже его загружайте в компилятор шейдеров.

[Для VC это ключ /P](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/p-preprocess-to-a-file?view=vs-2019)

Comment: glsl это с-подобный язык, не редко такие директивы понимает компилятор шейдеров (драйвера видеокарты)

Comment: Спасибо, кэп :) Теперь пойдемте ругаться с веселыми китайцами, которые не доложили препроцессор в свой компилятор.

Comment: Пометил как ответ, поскольку Вы ответили на тот вопрос, который был задан. К сожалению, в моем конкретном случае это не подойдет, т.к. мой код будет использовать шейдер, написанный другими людьми (и получать его в рантайме) и моя цель - максимальное упрощение процесса создания шейдеров и скрытие подробностей реализации взаимодействия кода и видеокарты.